# Print statement are not getting printed

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, arkit, alamofireimage

Why in my below code the print statement in the viewWillAppear block after the AlamofireImage have downloaded an image skips the rest of the code in the viewWillAppear block...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    Alamofire.request("https://example.com/four.png").responseImage { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        print(response.request as Any)
        print(response.response as Any)
        debugPrint(response.result)

        if let image = response.result.value {
            print("image downloaded: \(image)")

            self.imageServer.append(image)

            print("ImageServer append Successful")
            print("The new number of images = \(self.imageServer.count)")

        }
    }


///////////THESE STATEMENTS ARE BEING SKIPPED/////////////////
    print("The new number of images = \(imageServer.count)")
    print("Test")
    trackedImages = loadedImagesFromDirectoryContents(imageServer)
    configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
    configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah!! Great I just realized after reading your comment. Thanks a lot and could you please give a little hint about how I could get it working as I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `completionHandler` to solve this. Which will be executed once the `function` is complete.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    fetchImage {
        print("The new number of images = \(imageServer.count)")
        trackedImages = loadedImagesFromDirectoryContents(imageServer)
        configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

}

func fetchImage(completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    Alamofire.request("https://example.com/four.png").responseImage { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        print(response.request as Any)
        print(response.response as Any)
        debugPrint(response.result)

        if let image = response.result.value {
            print("image downloaded: \(image)")

            self.imageServer.append(image)

            print("ImageServer append Successful")
            print("The new number of images = \(self.imageServer.count)")

        }
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just putting the *notified* code into the completion closure?`DispatchGroup` is inappropriate for a single asynchronous operation.

Comment: I agree, it would be much better to make a function with a completionHandler. I can edit my answer for a better solution

Comment: Hey Jacob, I have one more question. When I used the ARReferenceImage method with inGroupNamed the arkit works wonderful but when I try to add my downloaded picture using Alamofire, the arkit detects it and plays the video but I can't see the video on my screen. Any idea why this is happening and if you want I can upload source code too.  THANKS